# Binding Image to Uri using Caliburn.Micro

Tags: silverlight, caliburn.micro

Why doesn't the following Image bind to the source properly?

```
<UserControl x:Class="SlCaliburnConventionTest.Sample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Image x:Name="UriProperty" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code behind and the view model:

```
namespace SlCaliburnConventionTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    public partial class Sample : UserControl
    {
        public Sample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var viewModel = new SampleViewModel("http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/1");
            Caliburn.Micro.ViewModelBinder.Bind(viewModel, this, null);
        }
    }

    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        public SampleViewModel(string url)
        {
            UriProperty = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
        }

        public Uri UriProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I dug into the Caliburn.Micro sources and found that it was not using the TypeDescriptor when applying the conventions. The question is: How do we persuade the Caliburn.Micro to convert Uris into ImageSource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image controls demonstrate an interesting property of XAML known as **type conversion**. For instance, the XAML api for Images look like this:

```
<Image Source="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people" />
```

However, the programming API is like this:

```
class Image {
   ImageSource Source { get; set;}
   DependencyProperty SourceProperty // etc.
}
```

How did a string get turned into an Uri, and then turned into an ImageSource?

The answer lies in TypeConverters.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ImageSourceConverter))]
public class ImageSource {}
```

When we programmatically create a binding to a Uri, the magic above doesn't take place. And the result is no pictures are shown.

```
// No picture is shown.
BindingOperations.SetBinding(myImage, 
  Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("MyUri"));
```

Similarly we cannot do this:

```
// compile time error
myImage.Source = new Uri("http://...")
```

Instead, the proper way is to fetch the type converter from the ImageSource's custom attribute and massage it into an IValueConverter. Here's mine - the main work is performed by this single line `public object Convert(...)` - everything else is scaffolding:

```
namespace Caliburn.Micro
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    public class ValueTypeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var result = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType).ConvertFrom(value);
            return result;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Binding Image.Source to an Uri typically fails.
        /// Calling the following during application bootstrap will set this up properly.
        ///    ConventionManager.ApplyValueConverter = ValueTypeConverter.ApplyValueConverter;
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="binding"></param>
        /// <param name="bindableProperty"></param>
        /// <param name="info"></param>
        public static void ApplyValueConverter(Binding binding, DependencyProperty bindableProperty, PropertyInfo info)
        {
            if (bindableProperty == UIElement.VisibilityProperty && typeof(bool).IsAssignableFrom(info.PropertyType))
                binding.Converter = ConventionManager.BooleanToVisibilityConverter;

            else if (bindableProperty == Image.SourceProperty && typeof(Uri).IsAssignableFrom(info.PropertyType))
                binding.Converter = new ValueTypeConverter();
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in _Conventions)
                {
                    if (bindableProperty == item.Item1 && item.Item2.IsAssignableFrom(info.PropertyType))
                        binding.Converter = new ValueTypeConverter();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If there is a TypeConverter that can convert a <paramref name="SourceType"/>
        /// to the type on <paramref name="bindableProperty"/>, then this has to
        /// be manually registered with Caliburn.Micro as Silverlight is unable to 
        /// extract sufficient TypeConverter information from a dependency property
        /// on its own.
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>
        /// ValueTypeConverter.AddTypeConverter&lt;ImageSource&gt;(Image.SourceProperty);
        /// </example>
        /// <typeparam name="SourceType"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="bindableProperty"></param>
        public static void AddTypeConverter<SourceType>(DependencyProperty bindableProperty)
        {
            _Conventions.Add(Tuple.Create<DependencyProperty, Type>(bindableProperty, typeof(SourceType)));
        }

        private static IList<Tuple<DependencyProperty, Type>> _Conventions = new List<Tuple<DependencyProperty, Type>>();
    }
}
```

Then in the bootstrapper, we wire up the new IValueConverter:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    // ...
    ConventionManager.ApplyValueConverter = 
      ValueTypeConverter.ApplyValueConverter;
}
```

Comment: Does Caliburn not allow to simply write `<Image Source="{Binding UriProperty}"/>`? Looks a lot easier to me.

Comment: And please note that *coercion* means something different. What you mean is called type conversion.

Comment: You are right on both counts. Thanks. I was actually investigating the use of type conversion for displaying images that can be replaced by the user, as it seemed to be a nice way of hiding much of the complexity associated.

Answer (score 3):

I use a string as the backing property and the binding works for me:

```
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        ImageUrl = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png";
    }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}

<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I was specifically trying to understand how to make TypeConverters work with Caliburn.Micro.